# Regression model that keeps relative error small

Tags: regression, fitting

I have data $Y= (y_1,..,y_n)$ that I want to fit this using parameters $X=(x_{ij}) \in \mathbb R^{n \times m}.$

When estimating the output $Y$ from data $X$, I care mostly about the relative error between estimated values and real values $Y$.
The issue here is that some of the $y_i$ are very large and others are very small, see below.

So if I would use something like linear regression, then the large ones gets estimated with very good relative error and the smaller values of $y_i$ get estimated with a very poor relative error.

What can I do in such a situation?

The data I want to fit is of the form

> ```
> y[0] = 44000000
> y[1] = 319780000
> y[2] = 2462400
> y[3] = 407000
> y[4] = 2584340
> y[5] = 18000000
> y[6] = 208200
> y[7] = 1127734790
> y[8] = 327924
> y[9] = 88650
> y[10] = 75000
> ```

Comment: Clarify your notation $x_{ij}$. Please joint to your question at least a representative example of your data (numerical, not graph).

Comment: @JJacquelin done, and the $x_{ij}$ are entries of the matrix $X$.

Comment: Data $y_i$ useless without data $x_{ij}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution could be to work in the logarithm scale in $Y$ i.e, the model predicts $log(y)$ instead of $y$.This can be done if your $Y$ is **strictly positive**).
Expanding a little bit:

- Your new target is $z = log(y)$
- Your predictions $\hat{z}$ can be thought as  $\hat{z} = log(\hat{y})$
- The distance now is $\hat{z} - z = log(\hat{y}) - log(y) = log(\frac{\hat{y}}{y})$
- Now with any **distance based loss** you are penalizing with the relative size $\frac{\hat{y}}{y}$

Finally to revert the transformation, the predictions would be $e^{\hat{z}}$ assuming that you took natural logarithms